# How can I test setResult() in an Android Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

Is there any good way to test the result code and data in an Android Espresso test? I am using Espresso 2.0.

Suppose I have an `Activity` called `BarActivity.class`, which upon performing some action, calls `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` with the appropriate payload.

I'd like to write a test case to verify the `resultCode` and `data`. However, because `setResult()` is a `final` method, I can't override it.

Some options I thought about were:

- Define a new method like `setActivityResult()` and just use that so it can be intercepted, etc...
- Write a test-only TestActivity that will call `startActivityForResult()` on `BarActivity` and check the result in `TestActivity.onActivityResult()`

Trying to think what's lesser of the two evils, or if there's any other suggestions on how to test for this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a partical solution for option 2: https://product.reverb.com/2016/03/12/testing-android-activity-results/ However, not complete, at least I didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to upgrade to 2.1, then take a look at [Espresso-Intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html):

> Using the intending API (cousin of Mockito.when), you can provide a response for activities that are launched with startActivityForResult

This basically means it is possible to build and return any result when a specific activity is launched (in your case the **BarActivity** class).

Check this example here: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html#intent-stubbing

And also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29923942/1368705) on a somewhat similar issue (but with the contact picker activity), in which I show how to build a result and send it back to the Activity which called *startActivityForResult()*

Comment: I don't see how to test the setResult method with Espresso-Intents. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 21):

If meanwhile you switched to the latest Espresso, version 3.0.1, you can simply use an `ActivityTestRule` and get the Activity result like this:

```
assertThat(rule.getActivityResult(), hasResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK));
assertThat(rule.getActivityResult(), hasResultData(IntentMatchers.hasExtraWithKey(PickActivity.EXTRA_PICKED_NUMBER)));
```

You can find a working example [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/ActivityResultTest.java).

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest way as long as you can go to 3.0.1.

Comment: If `hasResultCode` and `hasResultData` cannot be resolved.  Add  `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.1'` in build.gradle

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```kotlin
@Test
    fun testActivityForResult(){

        // Build the result to return when the activity is launched.
        val resultData = Intent()
        resultData.putExtra(KEY_VALUE_TO_RETURN, true)

        // Set up result stubbing when an intent sent to <ActivityB> is seen.
        intending(hasComponent("com.xxx.xxxty.ActivityB")) //Path of <ActivityB>
            .respondWith(
                Instrumentation.ActivityResult(
                    RESULT_OK,
                    resultData
                )
            )

        // User action that results in "ActivityB" activity being launched.
        onView(withId(R.id.view_id))
            .perform(click())

      // Assert that the data we set up above is shown.
     onView(withId(R.id.another_view_id)).check(matches(matches(isDisplayed())))
    }
```

Assuming a validation like below on **onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)**

```kotlin
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

    data?.getBooleanExtra(KEY_VALUE_TO_RETURN, false)?.let {showView ->
                if (showView) {
                 another_view_id.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }else{
                 another_view_id.visibility = View.GONE
                 }
            }
        }
```

I follow this guide as reference : https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents and also i had to check this links at the end of the above link https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample
and
https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsAdvancedSample

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) (or [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule)) as is the current recommendation in the Android Developers documentation (see the [Test your app's activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing) page), the [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) class offers a [getResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#getResult()) method which you can assert on as follows:

```kotlin
@Test
fun result_code_is_set() {
    val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(BarActivity::class.java)

    // TODO: execute some view actions which cause setResult() to be called

    // TODO: execute a view action which causes the activity to be finished

    val activityResult = activityScenario.result

    assertEquals(expectedResultCode, activityResult.resultCode)
    assertEquals(expectedResultData, activityResult.resultData)
}
```