# How to test Intent based on Espresso in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I want to test the Intent I'm sending from Activity A to Activity B. There are samples for that, [android-testing](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/DialerActivityTest.java) and [espresso.intent.Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.html).

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it into work. I want to test following method in my first Activity.

```
private void searchForDropOff()
    {
        this.startActivityForResult(PoiActivity.newIntent(this, PlacesAPIRequest.PARAM_SEARCH_TYPE_DESTINATION,
                        this.mBooking.getPickUp() != null ? this.getPickUp().getSafeLatLng() : this.mReferenceLatLng),
                        PlacesAPIRequest.PARAM_SEARCH_TYPE_DESTINATION);
    }
```

So, according to my references this is my test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class FirstActivityTest
{
    @Rule
    public final IntentsTestRule<FirstActivityTest> mRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(FirstActivityTest.class);

    @Before
    public void stubAllExternalIntents()
    {
        // By default Espresso Intents does not stub any Intents. Stubbing needs to be setup before
        // every test run. In this case all external Intents will be blocked.
        intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
    }

    @Test
    public void click_drop_off_box()
    {
        // Click drop-off box, POI activity displays
        onView(withId(R.id.booking_drop_off_layout)).perform(click());

        // Verify that an intent to the dialer was sent with the package.
        // Think of Intents intended API as the equivalent to Mockito's verify.
        intended(allOf(
                hasExtra(PoiActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH_TYPE, PlacesAPIRequest.PARAM_SEARCH_TYPE_DESTINATION),
                toPackage("com.XXX.passenger.poi.PoiActivity")));
    }
}
```

What I'm getting in Log:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: (has extras: has bundle with: key: is "addressType" value: is <2> and resolvesTo: com.xxx.passenger.poi.PoiActivity)

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:
-Intent { cmp=com.xxx.passenger/com.xxx.passenger.poi.PoiActivity (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.xxx.passenger]], extras:[Bundle[{referencePoint=lat/lng: (1.3650683,103.8313499), addressType=2}]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oh man, finally after two days I found the solution.
I Used `hasComponent` instead of `toPackage` and my test passed.
I'm not sure my conclusion is right but seems for checking our application's activities (Components) we should use `hasComponent` method.

So my change is:

```
intended(allOf(
                hasExtra(PoiActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH_TYPE, PlacesAPIRequest.PARAM_SEARCH_TYPE_DESTINATION),
                hasComponent("com.XXX.passenger.poi.PoiActivity")));
```

Comment: Yes, `package` (aka `applicationId`) is a grouping of `components` (i.e. stuff declared in the manifest).